# Code stops execution at a breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to coding and working on basic problems to learn the code. After building and running I encounter a breakpoint. I don't entirely know how to fix and am looking for guidance towards the right direction.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout.precision(2);
    // Define Constant and Variables
    const char POUND = 163;
    int pounds = 0;
    int shillings = 0;
    int pence = 0;
    double newPounds;

    // Keyboard out and in

    cout << "Enter amount of old pounds:";
    cin >> pounds;
    cout << "Enter amount of old shillings:";
    cin >> shillings;
    cout << "Enter amount of old pence:";
    cin >> pence;

    // Math to convert old to new

    newPounds = pounds + (shillings % 20) + (pence % 240);

    //Final output

    cout << "The value of the new currency is" << newPounds;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: IDE Screen of breakpoint]

Comment: Include your code in text .. not a snapshot.

Comment: Do you get an error? Or what's the deal with that breakpoint? If you get some diagnostic message, include it in your question.

Comment: @Downvoter, I'm getting a breakpoint. I can build the code and enter the pounds, shillings, and pence but one I get to the line to complete the conversion math it shuts down (line 29)

Comment: Did you set that yourself? If yes, just google for "remove breakpoint visual studio" or whatever your IDE is. If not, find out the reason and fix it. Some quick googling should be helpful already, I think.

Comment: @MohammadKanan: The screenshot shows the problem; the code does not.

Answer (score 2):

A breakpoint doesn't "shut it down"; a breakpoint is something that you set in your IDE, instructing the debugger to halt execution at a certain point in your program so that you may inspect some variables of interest.

If you don't want it any more, simply turn it off!

Here's the documentation for using breakpoints in Visual Studio:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

In the screenshot that somebody made you take out of the question, we can see that you have set a breakpoint on the line that starts `newPounds` — possibly a misclick? Click on the red circle to remove it.

Comment: Red circle means ERROR.

Comment: @RickAstley: No, it doesn't.

Comment: I know sarcasm is hard to notice through text.

Comment: Humor is highly subjective my friend

Comment: @RickAstley Humor is highly objective though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I didn't ask OP not to include a snapshot .. but its good to minimize snapshot contents to what can't be coded ..

Comment: @MohammadKanan: Yep okay. But you mean _screen_ shot?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why?

Comment: @MohammadKanan: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I didn't understand whats wrong with _snapshot_?

Comment: @MohammadKanan: It's not a picture of the screen. That's a screenshot. At least, it is where I live.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hmm good point .. I thought its common in computer informal terms

Comment: @MohammadKanan: As far as I know, "snapshot" means lots of other things but not screenshot. You could have a snapshot of a database, for example.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yeah .. that makes sense

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to you as well :)